# Attach data from one collection to results from another in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have 2 collections `companies` and `products` where `partnerId` in common. I need to find the names of the company `companies.name` which are not available in `products` collection matching the `partnerId`. How can I do that? I have tried in both the aggregate and SQL as follows

```
db.companies.aggregate([{$lookup: 
    {
     from: "products", 
     localField: "partner", 
     foreignField: "_id", 
     as: "products"
    }
}])
```

and

```
mb.runSQLQuery(`
       SELECT  name
FROM companies
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM products
  WHERE partnerId=companies.partnerId
`);
```

I am using nosqlbooster. The first query is returning all the documents of companies and the second query is throwing an error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using a 3rd party to create your MongoDB queries from SQL. SQL and MongoDB query language are very different and you will not be able to effectively or efficiently utilize this language by doing so.

As a rule, in document DBs the data should be stored [denormalized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization), unlike in transactional tabular databases where the data should normalized. So a better design would be to add the data as sub-documents i.e. a list inside the document or a dictionary/object within the document.

With the data design you have implemented, a simple query will not help - each query only runs on a single collection. However, you can use the [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)'s [`$loopup` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to enrich the results from one collection with results from another..